# Unable to create new Tracking ID for Google Analytics Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

**Summary:**

Since the launch of the Analytics "Apps and web (beta)" properties, it is no longer possible to create new Tracking IDs for tracking Application Data (screen hits, exceptions and so on) using the Measurement Protocol (v1).

Is there any way to create an Application Tracking ID? I'm not interested in tracking a Web App.
ds=app&t=screenview
-or-
ds=app&t=exception

When trying to create a property to measure an "App", the property is created as "Apps and web (beta)"

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Select an account.
- Select "Admin"
- In Properties column, "+ Create Property"
- Under "What do you want to measure?" select "Apps" and fill remaining data
- The new property is listed as "App + Web".
- In the property settings, in "Property details", no Tracking ID is provided. Only a Property ID